# Where are stored the migration files djangoseo.xxxx?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have some troubles with django-seo2.

```
Running migrations:
Applying djangoseo.0001_initial... 
Applying djangoseo.0002_auto_20170630_1000... OK
Applying djangoseo.0003_auto_20170630_1038... OK
Applying djangoseo.0004_auto_20170630_1041...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 34, in <module>
```

Where are stored the migration files djangoseo.xxxx ?

I do not see them under project nor under project/app.

Comment: why did you ask this question anyway. Whatever you have mentioned is default django behaviour and clearly specified in first tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution....weird

in my virtual environment directory
**...venv\lib\site-packages\djangoseo\migrations**

Comment: That's just how Python and Django work, nothing weird about it. Any third-party python package you install into a virtual environment is installed in `venv/lib/site-packages/`, and in the case of a Django app, the migrations are inside the package in the `migrations` directory.